# How can i automate Google map image on web page?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, maps, google-maps-markers, sikuli

I am not able to automate google map screen which is present on my application web page.

I have web page where google map is present in square in half of screen. I want to click on the road present in map or a restaurant logo which is present on the google map.

When i tried to find the locators for the map then in the DOM it is present as an image and no other html properties or locators are associated with it.

Also i tried an option using moveToElement() function of action class but this solution is not reliable as most of the time it is not working.

Please suggest me any solution for this automation issue if someone faced this issue of Google maps automation before ?

Comment: Search the DOM for this:  src="https://maps.google.com/maps?  it should be in an element.

Comment: I have searched it and it is getting identified as canvas image :). Please refer DOM below.<canvas width="1920" height="514" id="" class="widget-scene-canvas" style="width: 1536px; height: 411px;"></canvas>

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like HTML5  issue over a google maps issue.  This is tricky for Selenium, see these articles:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/html-canvas-testing-selenium-opencv-maciej-kusz/
https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/automated-testing-of-html5-canvas/

which recommend using action chains to move to and click certain x,y coordinates.

Also, check out the canvas javascript api; you may be able to use javascript_executor to manipulate the canvas.

Comment: https://ui.vision/ I found UI.Vision tool very useful for automating maps. Please check if anyone facing sililar scenarios.